# How accurate is it to use the kinetic gas theory equation of most probable speed on a water droplet?

Tags: approximations, kinetic-theory

> Find the most probable velocity of a water droplet of diameter $ d=  .10 \mu m$ suspended in air at
> temperature $17C$
> -From JEE question bank

The solution involves using the most probable speed expression:

$$ C_{mp} = \sqrt{ \frac{3RT}{M}} $$

And in place of $M$ you substitute $ \frac{\rho \pi d^3}{6}$ where $d$ is diameter.

While it may just be a routine calculation for a person who knows the most probable speed expression in KE theory, I found it a bit strange to apply the equations for substances which are not gases. So, I wondered how good of an approximation is it to take the speed water droplets by approximating it as a 'kinetic gas'?

I tried searching online but I couldn't find the relevant articles.